# How To Disable certain display is quite disturbing?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

How can I disable the tooltip (shown below) in Visual Studio? I find it annoying that it covers the above line.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqON8.png]

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question but a comment on the code in the picture: You are not allowed to call `main()`.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fb4e86d4-8153-4862-8091-c8960f45daa5/visual-studio-2017-hover-tips?forum=visualstudiogeneral